# Jasmine how to spy function inside object [Angular]?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a written method down below in the service `CapacitorManager`

```
backButtonHandler() {
        return () => {
            const activeModalInstance = this.dataService.getItem(Constants.activeModalInstanceKey);
            const doesActiveModalExist = activeModalInstance !== -1;
            if (doesActiveModalExist) {
                activeModalInstance.close();
            }
            else {
                this.location.back();
            }
        }
    }
```

this method should call method `close` inside the object `activeModalInstance(activeModalInstance is an instance of NgbModal)` in case there is `activeModalInstance` inside the instance where `dataService.getItem()` refers to.Method `getItem` already mocked to be returned as object including close method.

```
fdescribe('CapacitorManager', () => {
    let service: CapacitorManager;
    let dataService: DataService;
    let location: Location;
    let dataServiceStub: Partial<DataService>;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        dataServiceStub = {
            getItem: () => {
                return {
                    close: () => {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation },
                { provide: DataService, useValue: dataServiceStub },
                CapacitorManager
            ],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            service = TestBed.inject(CapacitorManager);
            dataService = TestBed.inject(DataService);
            location = TestBed.inject(Location);
        });
    }));

    afterEach(() => {
        service = null;
    });

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should backButtonHandler call activeModal in case activeModalInstance exists', () => {
        const activeModalInstance = dataService.getItem("activeModal");
        spyOn(activeModalInstance, "close");            
        service.backButtonHandler();
        expect(activeModalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(location.back).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Last test case where I'm testing `Expected a spy, but got Function.` . How can I succed this test case?

Answer (score 0):

So this threw me for a bit. I think the code below will work for you.
I have added comments to indicate what I changed to make it pass for me.

Last thoughts, check the line number to make sure that `expect(location.back).not.toHaveBeenCalled();` isn't what it is breaking on.

```
fit('should backButtonHandler call activeModal in case activeModalInstance exists', () => {
  const modal = {
    close: () => {

    }
  };
  // so it looks like because you return a new item EVERY TIME above, you spy on a different item than you think
  // here we set a specific object to return
  dataService.getItem = () => modal;
  const activeModalInstance = dataService.getItem("activeModal");
  spyOn(activeModalInstance, "close");
  const func = service.backButtonHandler();
  // Your capacitor manager, as written, is a function that returns a function.
  // to get it to run you have to call the function that gets returned
  func();
  expect(activeModalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(location.back).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Also marked an if statement here that typescript wasn't a fan of, as you have an object that you're comparing to -1

```
backButtonHandler() {
  return () => {
    const activeModalInstance = 
    this.dataService.getItem(Constants.activeModalInstanceKey);
    // not sure what this is checking (as written, maybe you translated)           
    const doesActiveModalExist = activeModalInstance !== -1;
    if (doesActiveModalExist) {
      activeModalInstance.close();
    }
    else {
      this.location.back();
    }
  }
}
```